# PHP logout system not working. (session_destroy on MAMP)

Tags: php, session, mamp, logout

I recently transferred my website from XAMPP to MAMP. The problem is that my logout system is no longer working. The logout widget:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

My logout page itself:

```
<?php 
session_start()
session_destroy()
header('Location:login.php');
?>
```

The weird thing is that when I change something to logout.php, such as making it a simple echo statement:

```
<?php 
echo 'test';

//session_start()
//session_destroy()
//header('Location:login.php');
?>
```

I still do not see 'test' in my browser; I just stay at index.php even though I have commented out the header in the page. I am 100% the link path is fine.

Wether or not I alter the logout.php file or not, I can see that the server has NOT deleted the session file in tmp/php. This is weird because I have allowed in MAC OS X everyone acces to read and write to this tmp/php folder.

OS: MAC OS X 
SERVER: Apache within MAMP 
PHP:5.4.4 
BROWSERS: Problem occurs in both Google Chrome & Safari

(This is my maiden voyage with posting a question on stackoverflow, if you tips to improve my questioning, please let me know)

Comment: If you "stay at **index.php**", you definitely won't see "test" in your browser as you said that you change **logout.php** to the `echo 'test';` statement. You should visit logout.php instead.

Comment: What error do you see when you type manualy path_to_logout.php in the url?

Comment: Could it be that you are hitting an error, but have error_reporting set to 0?

Comment: Note: Native PHP session files are not deleted immediately after session_destroy(). They are deleted at intervals specified by the [session configuration](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: This may sound silly but, what about the comma missing at the end of session_start and session_destroy? Try:

session_start();
session_destroy();

Comment: Allright we are getting closer: 

1.When I typed manually path_to logout.php I came to the page I saw that the session file was deleted from tmp/php.

However, when I go there with the link the session file in tmp/php was NOT deleted.

2. After the session file is deleted and I go back to index.php the first time index.php looks as if the user is still logged in. When refreshed, this changes and then it shows as if the user is logged out.

Please, help me if you know where I can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
<?
    session_start();

    $_SESSION = array();
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

I just clear $_SESSION, and it always works for me

Answer (score 1):

If calling logout.php when it containts the code below does not print `test` then there is something else wrong and it has nothing to do with the sessions.

```
<?php 
echo 'test';
//session_start()
//session_destroy()
//header('Location:login.php');
?>
```

You mention that it still shows the index.php, which makes me thing you have a rewrite rule in your `.htaccess` file which redirects the call from logout.php to the index. Check your htaccess file for any rules.

You can find information about [htaccess on MAMP](http://www.witheringtree.com/2010/03/htaccess-vs-mamp/) here

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I couldnt fix it. I have only one .htcacces file, not in my site root folder:

    Options -Indexes

I just tested the following: I changed the link in my menu to logout1.php and also made a logout1.php file; both logout.php and logout1.php are located in the site root folder.

In logout1.php I made a simple echo statement:

    <?php 
    echo 'test';
    ?>

Still this file isnt reached. All my other links in the menu work without any problem. Under XAMPP there was also no problem. Do you have a suggestion to fix this?

Comment: You say it isnt reached. What do you see? 404 not found error or another page?

Comment: For some reason the logout1.php is now simply displayed. So I see the 'test' is echoed. If you look at my comment above it that now two problems occur:

1. When I go to logout.php by clikcing on the link the session info file is not destroyed (I see that in finder).
2. If I go type in the address manually the session info file is deleted after some seconds.
3. If I go back to index.php it first seems as if I am logged in. Then I refresh, and index.php looked as if I am logged out.

Do you know a solution? (Thank you for your help so far!)

Comment: Addition: when I alter the link path in my menu.php from logout1.php to logout.php it takes quit some seconds before this is updated on the actual page (I do refresh after I have saved the changes). Maybe this info helps you.

Comment: And another addition: it seems that I only get the index.php for logged out people after I click the refresh button, thus:

1. Clicking on the link to the logout.php doesnt delete the session file; going there manually does delete the session file.
2. Then going back to index.php and clicking on a link to index.php then it still shows as if I am logged in. If i click refresh this changes.

Comment: I am a lot further with this problem now and it seems that some problems are caused by the PHP version MAMP was running:

http://phpacademy.org/forum/topic/mamp-settings-problem-on-image-uploading-site-visualupload-22957/page/mamp-settings-problem-on-image-uploading-site-visualupload-22957

Answer (score 0):

These are the essential parts of a logout, assuming that your scripts are using PHP sessions. Note that your logout script causes a parse error because it is missing semicolons at the end of statements.  Maybe just a typo.

```
<?php // RAY_EE_logout.php
session_start();

// CLEAR THE INFORMATION FROM THE $_SESSION ARRAY
$_SESSION = array();

// IF THE SESSION IS KEPT IN COOKIE, FORCE SESSION COOKIE TO EXPIRE
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
{
   $cookie_expires  = time() - date('Z') - 3600;
   setcookie(session_name(), '', $cookie_expires, '/');
}

// TELL PHP TO ELIMINATE THE SESSION
session_destroy();

// REDIRECT TO THE HOME PAGE
header("Location: /");
exit;
```

HTH, ~Ray

Answer (score 0):

Try using output buffer.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:login.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it had to do with the php code block not being defined correctly.  I had `<? ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

@tom.e.degroot:  Last time I checked, "it didnt work" was not an error message.  You'll need to describe the symptoms a little more.  Please follow the guidance here: http://SSCCE.org and give us something we can install and test on our own servers.  Thanks, ~Ray

Comment: Dear Ray,

Thank you for your construtive comment. I am new here and I am glad you gave me this useful tip. When I tried what you suggested I got a 404 error from my browser (hence, not the 404 message generated by CodeIgniter. Is this a better description?